# Prevent keyboard dismiss when tapping DropdownButton

Tags: flutter

This question pertains to Flutter. I have a DropdownButton above a TextField as follows:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
          isExpanded: true,
          hint: Text(associatedHint),
          disabledHint: Text(associatedHint),
          items: diagnosesList.map((int value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value.toString(),
              child: Text(dxDisplay),
            );
          }).toList(),
          value: ANID,
          onChanged: (String newANID) {
            setState(() {
              ANID = newANID;
            });
          },
        ),
        TextField(
          autofocus: true,
          keyboardType: keyboardType,
          maxLines: maxLines,
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
          controller: _textEntryController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Entry"),
          onChanged: (value) {
            noteEntry = value;
          },
        ),
```

The TextField autofocus brings up the keyboard immediately. When you tap the DropdownButton, it removes focus from TextField and thus dismisses the keyboard. This moves things around on the screen and creates a poor UX.

[image]
[image]

Any suggestions for how to fix this? Is there a way to keep the keyboard up even after the DropdownButton is tapped?

Comment: I suggest you trying dropdown_button2 package, cause it seems that from dropdown.dart file it handles "unfocus" event.

Answer (score 2):

The Focus widget manages a focus node, and is the workhorse of the focus system.
It's primary function to  manages the attaching and detaching of the focus node from the focus tree. please see below example it may help you

```
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Alert Dialog'),
          content: Container(
            width: 600,
            height: 200,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                DropdownButton<String>(
                  isExpanded: true,
                  onTap: (){
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_textFieldFocusNode);
                  },
                  hint: Text(associatedHint),
                  disabledHint: Text(associatedHint),
                  items: diagnosesList.map((int value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value.toString(),
                      child: Text(dxDisplay),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  value: ANID,
                  onChanged: (newANID) {
                    setState(() {
                      ANID = newANID.toString();
                    });
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_textFieldFocusNode);
                  },

                ),
                Focus(
                  onFocusChange: (focused) {
                    setState(() {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_textFieldFocusNode);
                    });
                  },

                  child: TextField(
                    focusNode: _textFieldFocusNode,
                    autofocus: true,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    maxLines: maxLines,
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                    controller: _textEntryController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Entry"),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      noteEntry = value;
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: const Text('Close'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

you may see a complete example on github https://github.com/karamatpkid/Preventkeyboarddismiss
and you can also visit official flutter documentation regarding [focus widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/advanced/focus#focus-widget)

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed my problem, i tried everything expect both Focus widget and ontap requestFocus on same time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. Need to wrap the AlertDialog in a SingleChildScrollView. This opens the AlertDialog at the top of the screen and doesn't move it when a keyboard opens/closes. It also makes sure that if the content gets too long (vertically), it can slide under the keyboard and user can use scroll gesture to see/interact with hidden content.

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: AlertDialog(
      title: alertTitle,
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget> [
          DropdownButton<String>(
            .......
          ),
          TextField(
            autofocus: true,
            .......
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
  );
```

Comment: For my case i'm in a `showModalBottomSheet` call, so I cannot wrap it with `SingleChildScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution using [dropdown_button2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2)

```
  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  bool hasFocus = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Dropdown Fix'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DropdownButton2(
              onMenuStateChange: (isOpen) {
                hasFocus = false;

                // this allows us to track whether or not you need to focus
                if (focusNode.hasFocus && isOpen && MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0) {
                  hasFocus = true;
                }

                if (hasFocus) {
                  // it should be called twice to provide focusNode being focused before DropdownButton2 inner calculations and after build method
                  focusNode.requestFocus();
                  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => focusNode.requestFocus());
                }
              },
              isExpanded: true,
              hint: const Text('associatedHint'),
              disabledHint: const Text('associatedHint'),
              // don't forget to remove `const` when providing a new value
              items: const [
                DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: 'value1',
                  child: Text('value1'),
                ),
                DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: 'value2',
                  child: Text('value2'),
                ),
              ],
              onChanged: (_) {
                // 
              },
              iconStyleData: const IconStyleData(),
              dropdownStyleData: const DropdownStyleData(),
              menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 200),
            TextField(
              focusNode: focusNode,
              // autofocus: true,
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Entry"),
              maxLines: 1,
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```